# Notepad++ RegEx remove between tags

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a KML file that has placemarks that I want to remove based on coordinates. Usually I would use `(?i)<Placemark>.*?</Placemark>` however this will remove everything contained between the placemarks. I need to only remove the placemark once it finds anything that matches 48.46 and higher.

Here is some sample data

```
<Placemark>
            <name>29.9167</name>
            <styleUrl>#falseColor1</styleUrl>
            <Polygon>
                <outerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                            48.4666,30.0000 46.3323,30.0000 
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
        </Placemark>
```

Comment: Regex is a great tool for finding "48.46", but it is an awful tool for the "and above" part.

Comment: How would I go about finding the 48.46?

Comment: Try `(?i)<Placemark>.*?48.46.*?</Placemark>`

Comment: You can use `48\.4[6-9][0-9]*|49(?:\.[0-9]+)?|[5-9][0-9](?:\.[0-9]+)?|[1-9][0-9]{2,}(?:\.[0-9]+)?` to find number greater than `48.46`

Comment: To match float numbers higher than `48.46`: `(?<!\d\.)\b(?:48\.4[6-9][0-9]*|49(?:\.[0-9]+)?|[5-9][0-9](?:\.[0-9]+)?|[1-9][0-9]{2,}(?:\.[0-‌​9]+)?)\b(?!\.\d)`. To match all inside the block that has that number: `(?s)<Placemark>(?:(?!</?Placemark>).)*?(?<!\d\.)\b(?:48\.4[6-9][0-9]*|49(?:\.[0-9]+)?|[5-9][0-9](?:\.[0-9]+)?|[1-9][0-9]{2,}(?:\.[0-‌​9]+)?)\b(?!\.\d)(?:(?!</?Placemark>).)*?</Placemark>`